# Unable to properly communicate with the workflow service

Tags: 2013, workflow, workflow-manager

Hi we are having a problem in our production environment, all of our Applications with Workflow 2013 are no longer working since yesterday.

I already did below steps but still no luck:

1. Restart and Recycle WorkflowMngmt App Pool
2. Restart WorkflowManager Backend

[image]

This is what I get in ULS Log

```
    Exception   System.TimeoutException: The HTTP request has timed out after 20000 milliseconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.OnGotResponse(IAsyncResult result)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManagementClient.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowM...  92dc9a9d-87d8-803e-9c20-e35f96b51474
08/17/2016 22:05:50.06* w3wp.exe (ProductionWeb:0x3B34)         0x4224  SharePoint Server               Workflow Services               aidax   Exception   ...anager.Publish(WorkflowDescription description, Boolean terminateActiveInstances)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowManagementClient.PublishWorkflow(String serviceGroupName, WorkflowDescription workflow)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowProxy.CreateDefinitionSubscription(String subscriptionName, String eventSource, List`1 eventTypes, String definitionName, IDictionary`2 metadata, WorkflowEventContext eventContext) StackTrace:  at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (sig=b37eb49a-4fb5-42f6-b173-5fd60276c25a|2|microsoft.office.server.native.pdb, offset=135DA) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (offset=21F8D)   92dc9a9d-87d8-803e-9c20-e35f96b51474
08/17/2016 22:05:50.06  w3wp.exe (ProductionWeb:0x3B34)         0x4224  SharePoint Server               Unified Logging Service         c91s    Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: SharePoint Server 2013, ULSException14, 044806dd "sharepoint server", 0f0011db "15.0.4571.0", 8b1d9bdf "microsoft.workflow.common", 01009cc3 "1.0.40131.0", 52ef34a6 "mon feb 03 00:18:14 2014", 0000003b "0000003b", 000000b9 "000000b9", e19bc27f "timeoutexception", 00203017 "aidax"  92dc9a9d-87d8-803e-9c20-e35f96b51474
08/17/2016 22:05:50.06  w3wp.exe (ProductionWeb:0x3B34)         0x4224  SharePoint Server               Workflow Services               ajafj   Medium  Error publishing workflow subscription (republish or retry publish) information: System.TimeoutException: The HTTP request has timed out after 20000 milliseconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.OnGotResponse(IAsyncResult result)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManagementClient.SendRequest[... 92dc9a9d-87d8-803e-9c20-e35f96b51474
08/17/2016 22:05:50.06* w3wp.exe (ProductionWeb:0x3B34)         0x4224  SharePoint Server               Workflow Services               ajafj   Medium  ...T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManager.Publish(WorkflowDescription description, Boolean terminateActiveInstances)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowManagementClient.PublishWorkflow(String serviceGroupName, WorkflowDescription workflow)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowProxy.CreateDefinitionSubscription(String subscriptionName, String eventSource, List`1 eventTypes, String definitionName, IDictionary`2 metadata, WorkflowEventContext eventContext)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricSubscriptionService.<>c__DisplayClass1.<CreateDefinitionSubscription>b__0()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceContextExtensions.InvokeWithEcosystemRetry(WorkflowServicesContext con...  92dc9a9d-87d8-803e-9c20-e35f96b51474
08/17/2016 22:05:50.06* w3wp.exe (ProductionWeb:0x3B34)         0x4224  SharePoint Server               Workflow Services               ajafj   Medium  ...text, EcosystemRequiredMethod method)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricSubscriptionService.CreateDefinitionSubscription(String subscriptionName, Guid eventSourceId, String eventSource, List`1 eventNames, String definitionName, IDictionary`2 metadata, WorkflowEventContext eventContext)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscriptionStorageEventReceiver.ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties) 92dc9a9d-87d8-803e-9c20-e35f96b51474
08/17/2016 22:05:50.06  w3wp.exe (ProductionWeb:0x3B34)         0x4224  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (Event Receiver (Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscriptionStorageEventReceiver)). Execution Time=20291.5919481387   92dc9a9d-87d8-803e-9c20-e35f96b51474
08/17/2016 22:05:50.06  w3wp.exe (ProductionWeb:0x3B34)         0x4224  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8kh7    High    System.TimeoutException: The HTTP request has timed out after 20000 milliseconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.OnGotResponse(IAsyncResult result)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.Ht    92dc9a9d-87d8-803e-9c20-e35f96b51474
```

I can still published the workflow and access 12290 WorkflowUri though.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: did you check the ULS logs for the correlation ID?

Comment: yes but I cant find the correlation ID.

Comment: run the Merge-SPlogfile command like Merge-SPLogFile -Path "C:\Logs\FarmMergedLog.log" -correlation "Copy the Correlation iD"

Comment: Looks Ike u are getting timeout exception...

Comment: Do u have antivirus? Can u access workflow uri from sharepoint server? May be try to re register workflow proxy? Are u using https with workflow then check the ssl certa

Comment: Lastly also check the service bus services from workflow manager servers as these services are responsible for the communications. Please make sure service bus gateway and service bus message broker service started on all wf manager servers. If these are already started try to restart them.

Comment: Thanks @WaqasSarwarMCSE that's the fix. I saw the two services and its stops running I don't know why.

Comment: Great, I added that as answer so that everybody get benefits from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a time-out error that means SharePoint is unable to communicate with the workflow manager sever.

Service bus at workflow manager is responsible for the communication between SharePoint and WFM. Please make sure these 2 services are started on all WFM servers.

1. Service bus gateway
2. Service bus message broker

> Check also [Service Bus Message Broker Stuck on Starting](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/service-bus-message-broker-stuck-on-starting/) and [Workflow Manager Health Checklist](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/workflow-manager-health-checklist-in-sharepoint/)