# Create subsite with custom template timeout error on /_layouts/15/newsbweb.aspx

Tags: 2016, site-template, solution-package, sandbox-solution, time-out

We are using SP2016 on-premise and have a custom site template. The template is a wsp file upload via Site Settings -> Solution. The same template is working a year before. Also it is working in our test environment.
Today we try to create a subsite using this template. After we press create, it loads for 10 minutes. During the 10 minutes we see the subsite is actually created by browse it. However after it is timeout, an error displayed:

> System.TimeoutException: The HTTP request has timed out after 200000
>   milliseconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted:
>   The request was canceled.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.OnGotResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.H

When I refresh the subsite URL, the subsite is removed and left an 404 error.

By checking the ULS log, the error is

> Application error when access /_layouts/15/newsbweb.aspx,
>   Error=0x81020089System.TimeoutException:
>   The HTTP request has timed out after 200000 milliseconds. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was
>   canceled.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)     at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.OnGotResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.H   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.UpdateFileOrFolderProperties(String
>   bstrWebUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, String bstrCheckLockId, Object
>   varProperties, Boolean fMigrationSemantics, Boolean fSystemUpdate,
>   Boolean fUseIncomingLastModifiedTime, Boolean fIncrementItemVersion,
>   String etagMatch, Guid& pgOriginatorId, String& pbNewETag, Byte&
>   piLevel)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateFileOrFolderProperties(String
>   bstrWebUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, String bstrCheckLockId, Object
>   varProperties, Boolean fMigrationSemantics, Boolean fSystemUpdate,
>   Boolean fUseIncomingLastModifiedTime, Boolean fIncrementItemVersion,
>   String etagMatch, Guid& pgOriginatorId, String& pbNewETag, Byte&
>   piLevel)  d7fd449f-dba4-30b8-19f4-94ce6a8e3936

What could be the issue and how should I further troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

There are over 80,000 lines of ULS log with same correlation ID. By checking only the Critical and High level log, there is nothing wrong. By check one of medium log I found this line of error `Error publishing workflow subscription (republish or retry publish)` and than by [follow this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190931/unable-to-properly-communicate-with-the-workflow-service), it is solved.

The Workflow manager server 2 services:

- Service bus gateway
- Service bus message broker

Are stopped after someone reboot the server. After restarted these 2 services, subsite creation resumed to normal.